# Clicking button with selenium doesn't throw exception but the button isn't actually clicking?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click a button, which once clicked some text should appear. Selenium is not throwing any errors which means the buttons should have been clicked however the text is not appearing (it works manually).

```
<button class = "redButton one">
<img src = "images/name.png" class = redImage">
"Name"
</button>
```

I tried to click the button with the xpath: "//button[contains(text(), 'Name')]". I don't understand why the text is not appearing.

Comment: This may be caused by several issues. We can't help here without seeng all your code to make some basic debugging

Comment: try with //img[@src='images/name.png']  (If that image is unique...)  The click event should bubble-up to the button.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected text to be displayed after button click event? In order to help with this request, provide the HTML snippet of `<button>` before & after click event. Since this is working fine manually, did you try adding adequate wait time for the text to display?